# Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0'

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting that error the following error whenever I run my sample project.

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0];
```

Full error log [here](http://pastebin.com/DRvPkRdB).

Here's my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        classpath:/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        classpath:/WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>       
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>      
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here's my `root-context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->     
</beans>
```

Here's `OAuth2SecurityConfiguration.java`:

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.DefaultOAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.AuthenticationScheme;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableOAuth2Client;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Resource
    @Qualifier("accessTokenRequest")
    private AccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequest;

    @Bean
    @Scope("session")
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails googleResource() {
        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        details.setId("google-oauth-client");
        details.setClientId(env.getProperty("google.client.id"));
        details.setClientSecret(env.getProperty("google.client.secret"));
        details.setAccessTokenUri(env.getProperty("google.accessTokenUri"));
        details.setUserAuthorizationUri(env.getProperty("google.userAuthorizationUri"));
        details.setTokenName(env.getProperty("google.authorization.code"));
        String commaSeparatedScopes = env.getProperty("google.auth.scope");
        details.setScope(parseScopes(commaSeparatedScopes));
        details.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri(env.getProperty("google.preestablished.redirect.url"));
        details.setUseCurrentUri(false);
        details.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.query);
        details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
        return details;
    }

    private List<String> parseScopes(String commaSeparatedScopes) {
        List<String> scopes = newArrayList();
        Collections.addAll(scopes, commaSeparatedScopes.split(","));
        return scopes;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public OAuth2RestTemplate googleRestTemplate() {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(googleResource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(accessTokenRequest));
    }
}
```

And here's `SecurityWebAppInitializer.java`:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

@Order(1)
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:/WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml"})
public class SecurityWebAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

And finally, the problem child (if I'm correct), `security-context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
<sec:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <sec:http-basic/>
    <sec:logout/>
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false"/>

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
    <sec:custom-filter ref="oauth2ClientContextFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER"/>
    <sec:custom-filter ref="oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR"/>
</sec:http>
<b:bean id="oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <b:constructor-arg name="defaultFilterProcessesUrl" value="/googleLogin"/>
    <b:property name="restTemplate" ref="googleRestTemplate"/>
    <b:property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices"/>
</b:bean>
<b:bean id="tokenServices" class="com.rst.oauth2.google.security.GoogleTokenServices">
    <b:property name="checkTokenEndpointUrl" value="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo"/>
    <b:property name="clientId" value="${google.client.id}"/>
    <b:property name="clientSecret" value="${google.client.secret}"/>
    <b:property name="accessTokenConverter">
        <b:bean class="com.rst.oauth2.google.security.GoogleAccessTokenConverter">
            <b:property name="userTokenConverter">
                <b:bean class="com.rst.oauth2.google.security.DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter"/>
            </b:property>
        </b:bean>
    </b:property>
</b:bean>
<b:bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <b:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/googleLogin"/>
</b:bean>
<sec:authentication-manager alias="alternateAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider>
        <sec:user-service>
            <sec:user name="user" password="password" authorities="DOMAIN_USER"/>
        </sec:user-service>
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

I know it has something to do with one of the classes, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You can easily mix xml and java configuration in Spring. But you **must** choose an initialization order ! Here `web.xml` says you first load xml files, but you have a `SecurityWebAppInitializer` that also tries to load an xml file. It should be harmless because it should be ignored with `version=2.5` in web.xml file but it does not help to understand your problem !

Answer (score 2):

you need to add security filter on your `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Duplicate Filter registration for 'springSecurityFilterChain'. Check to ensure the Filter is only configured once.` below `SEVERE: A child container failed during start`. Did I miss anything? Anything else I could provide?

Comment: @zack_falcon Do you use java configuration besides the xml config you posted ?

Comment: There's a `OAuth2SecurityConfiguration.java`. I've posted up the code.

Comment: Also added a `SecurityWebAppInitializer.java`. It was initially set to `classpath:security-context.xml`. Tried changing it to the one above. Still getting a Tomcat couldn't start crap. Tried removing the security filter, and I'm back to square one.

Comment: @zack_falcon either you add the filter on the web.xml or you configure a SecurityWebAppInitializer, you can't use them both cause you will end up with a duplicate Filter

Comment: if I disable the filters and the `classpath:/WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml` in `web.xml`, I get the `Duplicate Filter` error. If I disable only the filters, then I get the error as noted in my question. Other errors include `No bean named 'oauth2ClientContextFilter' is defined`, etc (linked in the question). For reference, I'm trying to copy, study, and make a version of this: https://github.com/skate056/spring-security-oauth2-google

Comment: Scratch the first part. When I disabled traces of spring security from `web.xml`, I get a `No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined`... Hmmmm...